# Android Service can't open database, because (activity / context /this) is null

Tags: android, sqlite, service, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I need from MyService (extends Service) start new AsyncLoadJSONDoc(this).execute(), but problem is "this" can't be there.
If im working from Activity there is no problem, i just have to create constructor for taking activity in asynctask.
The main problem is i need OPEN my database below in asynctask from service (null pointer exception)
Service is checking cloud for new information and saving in the android database. (every minute)

```
public class AsyncLoadJSONDoc extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, ArrayList<Storage.JSONDocument>> {
private static final String TAG = "AsyncLoadJSONDoc";
Activity mActivity;`
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Date date = new Date();

private static final String TAG = "AsyncLoadJSONDoc";
Activity mActivity;    

public AsyncLoadJSONDoc(Activity activity){
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Storage.JSONDocument> doInBackground(URL... params) {
    StorageService storageService = App42API.buildStorageService();
    Storage storage = storageService.findAllDocuments(
            Constants.CLOUD_DB_NAME, Constants.COLLECTION_NAME);
    ArrayList<Storage.JSONDocument> jsonDocList = storage.getJsonDocList();
    Log.i(TAG, "Velikost databaze> " + jsonDocList.size());
    return jsonDocList;
}


protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Storage.JSONDocument> jsonDocList) {
    saveToDatabase(jsonDocList);
}

private void saveToDatabase(ArrayList<Storage.JSONDocument> jsonDocs) {
    Log.i(TAG, "saveToDatabase");
    Log.i(TAG + " Start>", df.format(date));

    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(mActivity)).getWritableDatabase(); // <---There is null exception
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    DatabaseHelper dq = new DatabaseHelper(mActivity);
    dq.onUpgrade(db, 1, 2);

    for(Storage.JSONDocument oneJsonDoc : jsonDocs) {
        cv.put(Constants.UPDATED_AT, oneJsonDoc.getUpdatedAt());
        cv.put(Constants.CREATED_AT, oneJsonDoc.getCreatedAt());
        cv.put(Constants.DOC_ID, oneJsonDoc.getDocId());
        cv.put(Constants.JSON, oneJsonDoc.getJsonDoc());
        if (oneJsonDoc.getLocation() == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location NULL");
            cv.put(Constants.LATITUDE, (byte[]) null);
            cv.put(Constants.LONGITUDE, (byte[]) null);
        } else {
            cv.put(Constants.LATITUDE, oneJsonDoc.getLocation().getLat().floatValue());
            cv.put(Constants.LONGITUDE, oneJsonDoc.getLocation().getLng().floatValue());
        }
        db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, Constants.JSON, cv);
        Log.i(TAG, "insert");
    }
    db.close();
    Log.i(TAG + " End>", df.format(date));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is a very simple fix, the `DatabaseOpenHelper` only needs a context, not the actual activity, so u can just change the constructor:

```
public class AsyncLoadJSONDoc extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, ArrayList<Storage.JSONDocument>> {

private Context mContext;

   public AsyncLoadJSONDoc(Context context){
       mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
   }
```

and replace with `mContext` in `new DatabaseHelper(mContext)`

Also you should delete those lines:

```
DatabaseHelper dq = new DatabaseHelper(mActivity);
dq.onUpgrade(db, 1, 2);
```

They are simply wrong. You should never call `onUpgrade`, the system automatically calls it for you when necessary.